# how to get level (height) where user is holding his device

Tags: android, gps

I'm working on AR application and I need now to get the height level of the phone. I mean I want to know if user is holding his phone 10cm above the ground or maybe 1m abouve the ground.

My first thought was to use GPS but after some time I've start to think that is pointles cause even if I'll the this coordinate from GPS that it won't be the level where user is holding his mobile but the level abouve the see level. Or maybe I'm wrong ?

Please advise

Comment: It is impossible. Why you think that this could be possible?

Comment: I am looking for solution. Ok GPS i wrong option, maybe something else ?

Comment: Some devices have a proximity sensor. That's the only sensor on a usual android device with such a accuracy.

Comment: proximity sensor has like 5-10cm of range (I've just checked in the service mode of my phone) so it is not the solution. But thanks for the info !!

Answer (score 0):

I made several AR applications before, I would like to know what type of AR application are you making.

The height from ground is not detectable as it is very inaccurate.

If you meant to detect the ground, you may need a AR marker on the ground instead

Comment: the end of the app is a bit fluid at the moment :) But the thing that I'm doing now is the object detection combined with calculating the distance. I can detect that the object I'm looking using my camera is a car, now I want to mesure the distance from me to the car. I wanted to get the angle, height and calculate the distance. Maybe I should change the aproach ?

Comment: well, is there any mathematical proof behind this? Vision from single view point won't give any accurate result

Comment: yes there is. It is a simple triangle. Phone is creating the base of it with ground (you have the height), you need also angle that the camera is making while looking at the connection of the object with ground: d = h * tan(a). That is why I'm looking for the way to have the h. I can assume that the user is holding phone on the eye level but I would like to have something better :)